# Why line count job runs slower in spark shell than a mapreduce job

Tags: apache-spark

I did a test to compare the performance between spark and mapreduce. I have three node cluster with 128GB memory each.

I run a job to calculate how many lines in a 10GB file.

I run line count job with mapreduce with the default configuration of hadoop. It just takes me about 23 seconds.

When I run the line count job in spark shell with 8GB memory per node.It takes me more than 6 minutes which really astonish me.

Here is the command to start spark-shell and code of spark job.

```
spark-shell --master  spark://10.8.12.16:7077 --executor-memory 8G
val s= sc.textFile("hdfs://ns/alluxio/linecount/10G.txt")
s.count()
```

Here comes my config file of spark:

spark-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/appadmin/jdk1.8.0_77
export SPARK_HOME=/home/appadmin/spark-2.0.0-bin-without-hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/appadmin/hadoop-2.7.2
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/home/appadmin/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop classpath)
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_LIBARY_PATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=10.8.12.16
SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=28686
SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/home/appadmin/spark-2.0.0-bin-without-hadoop/sparkdata/local
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=10g


SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/home/appadmin/spark-2.0.0-bin-without-hadoop/sparkdata/work
SPARK_LOG_DIR=/home/appadmin/spark-2.0.0-bin-without-hadoop/logs
```

spark-default.conf

```
spark.driver.memory              5g
spark.eventLog.dir      hdfs://10.8.12.16:9000/spark-event-log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass number of Partitions i.e defaultMinPartitions 
adjust number of partitions

like this

```
sc.textFile(file, numPartitions)
  .count()
```

you can also try `repartition` after loading to see the effect.
Also, have a look at [how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/)

You can further debug and adjust settings by printing

```
sc.getConf.getAll.mkString("\n")
```

Also can get number of executors like below example snippet.

```
/** Method that just returns the current active/registered executors
        * excluding the driver.
        * @param sc The spark context to retrieve registered executors.
        * @return a list of executors each in the form of host:port.
        */
       def currentActiveExecutors(sc: SparkContext): Seq[String] = {
         val allExecutors = sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus.map(_._1)
         val driverHost: String = sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.host")
         allExecutors.filter(! _.split(":")(0).equals(driverHost)).toList
       }

sc.getConf.getInt("spark.executor.instances", 1)
```

`getExecutorStorageStatus` and `getExecutorMemoryStatus` both return the number of executors including driver.

Comment: I followed your advice and get the result little better. The spark job takes 1 minutes to finish. However, my mapreduce job only take 23 seconds. Does mapreduce job keep the data in os cache which makes it performe better than spark job? The spark job may do not use the data in cache. Is that possible?

Comment: updated my answer. you have to debug little more, I have done both mapreduce and spark both were production grade code. but my observation is spark is slow if  we wont tune parameters correctly we felt mapreduce was better in terms of speed. after multiple ways of looking at performance tuning in spark. we were able to see drastic changes in speed. Finally we were able to prove that spark code runs faster for same logic.. please further fine tune parameters by understanding them in little bit more in depth. :-)

Comment: any other findings in fine tuning. Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Thanks. Now I know the key point why spark job runs slower than mapreduce. Tunning is important. I will take some work to tune my spark job with the docs you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spark runs with one executor. I would change my setup to be:

Leave 8GB on each machine for OS and other processes overhead. That would leave you with 120GB. Given that the garbage collector starts to degrade if you have more than around 32GB, I'd have 4 executors per machine with 30GB each.

So, I would set:

- `spark.executor.instances` = 12
- `spark.executor.cores` = (number of cores each of your machines has - 1) / 4 (leave 1 for OS)
- `spark.executor.memory` = 30g

Then run your application again.

Comment: It really works. But the spark job still spend more time which takes me more than 1 minutes. The spark job still much lower than MR. When I run the spark job with command "s.count()",it take about 1minutes stuck in "[Stage 2:>                                                        (0 + 80) / 80]" . When the progress bar moves, it spend about 20 seconds to finish. Why this happened?